# Counting all other types but the current one

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase, sum, average

I'm trying to write this query, that would calculate the average value of all the columns except the one that contains the type value, which I'm grouping the whole query by.

So for 4 types for example, each column in the resulting table will contain the average of all the other three type's values, i need to exclude the current type's rows.

As an example, if I was to calculate each type's average value for itself, the query would look like:

```
SELECT

SUM(some value) / COUNT(TYPE)

FROM TEMPTABLE
GROUP BY TYPE
```

Now I'm trying to calculate the other three's total average. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you mean columns, not rows? Can you post the table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one query to get the distinct types, and `LEFT JOIN` the same table, checking for type-inequality:

```
SELECT t1.type,
       SUM(t2.some_value) / COUNT(t2.type)
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT type FROM temptable ) t1
LEFT JOIN temptable t2 ON ( t1.type <> t2.type )
GROUP BY t1.type
```

Since you only want the average, you could replace the line

```
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT type FROM temptable ) t1
```

by

```
FROM temptable t1
```

but the first solution might perform better, since the number of rows is reduced earlier.

Comment: thanks, I guess I need to write something like this as nested query, because this part is only a member in a giant SELECT. so I can't use FROM or WHERE directly

Comment: There should be no reason why Peter's answer can't work as a sub-/nested query, should there? (My Sybase is rusty)

Comment: well, I subtracted the current value from the sum and divided that into (COUNT -1). i didnt test your solution but it seems good.

Answer (score 0):

The starting point here is to make a cartesian join between your types and your temptable (guessing your tables structure is : type(id, type), valueTable(id, type_id, some_value))

The following query

> SELECT t.type, SUM(vt.someValue) /
>   COUNT (*) AS sum FROM type t,
>   valueTable vt WHERE vt.type_id != t.id
>   GROUP BY t.type

should do the trick.

Comment: thx, though I'm inserting into valueTable. There's only temptable in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Should work on Sybase too:

```
SELECT
   SUM(some value) / SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM TEMPTABLE
GROUP BY TYPE
```

Comment: yea it's true but the query will be doing this for each type. so i dont wanna use a constant value

Answer (score 0):

Will this do what you need?

(Possibly with another `CASE` statement to avoid divide by zero errors if there is a possibility none of a type might be returned, I've also not explicitly accounted for the case that `type` is NULL)

```
SELECT

SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE <> 'Type1' THEN someValue ELSE 0 END) / 
     SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Type1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS T1,

SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE <> 'Type2' THEN someValue ELSE 0 END) / 
     SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Type2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS T2,

SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE <> 'Type3' THEN someValue ELSE 0 END) / 
     SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Type3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS T3,

SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE <> 'Type4' THEN someValue ELSE 0 END) / 
     SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Type4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS T4
FROM TEMPTABLE
```

Comment: thx that's actually not a bad idea, but I instead subtracted the current value from the sum and divided that into (COUNT -1)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just use this:

```
SELECT type, avg(col_01)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY type
```